# how to stop giving reward point after 1 commenting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

5
i want to if user comment 1st time grant reward +5 after another comment should not get reward 
here is my controller logic

```
public function comment($automobile, Request $request){
    $automobile = Automobile::where('slug', $automobile)->firstorfail();
    $comment = new Automobilecomment;
    $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->automobile_id = $automobile->id;
    $comment->comment = $request->comment;
    $comment->save();
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $reward = 5;
    $currentreward = $user->reward;
    $user->reward = $currentreward + $reward;
    $user->save();
    return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Comment Success');
}
```

if u need more information let me know because i never did this before like this

Comment: maintain reward table and check before its exist. As well you need separate codes for all reward items

Comment: Try to keep in database if user made first comment or not. Ten check if you should reward or not.

Comment: can u send me code because i can't understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`

```
public function comment($automobile, Request $request){
    $check = Automobile::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('automobile_id', $automobile->id)->get()->first();

    $automobile = Automobile::where('slug', $automobile)->firstorfail();
    $comment = new Automobilecomment;
    $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->automobile_id = $automobile->id;
    $comment->comment = $request->comment;
    $comment->save();

if(!$check)
{
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $reward = 5;
    $currentreward = $user->reward;
    $user->reward = $currentreward + $reward;
    $user->save();
}
    return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Comment Success');
}`
```